# Typeconflict with array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I wrote a script which shows all running tasks in windows.
As a feature for fun i try to filter the tasks by their `PID`.
But i get the following error message if i try to execute my script:

`Typeconflict: 'myArray(...)'`

**Code:** (I marked the line where the error occurs in the code.)

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /C tasklist")
strText = ""

Do Until objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll()
Loop

first_run               = true
last_char_was_space     = true
newString               = ""
DatensatzCounter        = 0
length                  = Len(strText)

For i=1 To length
    charx = Mid(strText,i,1)

    if charx = vbLf then
        newString = newString & ";"
        DatensatzCounter = DatensatzCounter + 1
    end if

    If charx <> " " Then
        if last_char_was_space and not first_run then
            newString = newString & ";"
        end if

        newString = newString & charx
        last_char_was_space = false
        first_run = false

    Elseif charx = " " Then
        last_char_was_space = true
    End If
Next

myArray = split(newString, ";")
'wscript.echo newString

i           = 3
Mult        = i * 6
save_mult   = Array()

For Datensatz=0 To DatensatzCounter-1
    if myArray(2 + Mult) < 500 then             '<---------ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE ------------ 
        ReDim Preserve save_mult(UBound(save_mult) + 1)
        save_mult(UBound(save_mult)) = Mult
    end if
    i = i + 1
    Mult = i * 6
Next

For i=0 To UBound(save_mult)
    wscript.echo "Prozessname: " & myArray(0 + save_mult(i)) & vbCrLf & "PID: " & myArray(1 + save_mult(i))
Next
```

I can't figure out why i get this error. I thought it is because the value from the array is a string and i try to compare it with an integer, so i wrote this litte script to check if it is possible to compare string with integer.

**Code:**

```
mystring = "Hello;123;World"
myArray = split(mystring, ";")

wscript.echo myArray(1)

if myArray(1) > 100 then
    wscript.echo "success!"
end if
```

I got `success!`, so it must be possible. I even tried to convert the Array value to int before comparing it:

```
if CInt(myArray(2 + Mult)) < 500 then
```

But then i get `Typeconflict: 'CInt'`

Comment: It seems that for some values `myArray(1 + Mult)` isn't a string which can be converted to an int. `"123" > 1` is okay but I don't think that `"Hello" > 1` is okay.

Comment: I figured out that one process has a space in it's name "Core Temp.exe", so my parser does remove the space and replace it with a semicolon and the whole index is getting shifted, this was the cause. I have to build in a check for such process names. Thank you for your hint!! :)

Comment: Update: Now i figured out that this was not the only problem, another problem was that 'DatensatzCounter' was too high, i had to reduce it's value by 4 before the loop to make it work, i can't explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make life easier on yourself by using some of the options available for `tasklist`. The default table view of the data has a variable number of spaces separating the fields. As you have discovered, this makes parsing those lines difficult. This can be switched to a csv format by using `\fo csv`. The header is still annoying for parsing purposes. You can eliminate it by using `\nh`. If you type

```
tasklist \fo csv \nh
```

at a command prompt you see that all of the lines look like

```
"System Idle Process","0","Services","0","24 K"
```

the embedded quotes are a hassle, but you can strip them from the overall line and then split on `","` (which becomes the somewhat unreadable VBScript literal `""","""` because of the ways double quotes are escaped) to get to the entries.

Also -- I don't think that it is efficient to use ReDim Preserve in a loop. My preference is to first begin with an array which is big enough to encompass your data and then use ReDim Preserve to trim it down to its final size.

Combining this you get something like the following:

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /C tasklist /fo csv /nh")

Do Until objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll()
Loop

lines = Split(strText, vbCRLF)
Dim target()
ReDim target(Ubound(lines))
j = -1

For i = 0 To UBound(lines)
    line = Trim(lines(i))
    if Len(line) > 1 Then
        line = Mid(line,2,Len(line)-2) 'remove outer "
        line = Split(line, """,""") 'split on ","
        If CInt(line(1)) < 500 Then
            j = j + 1
            target(j) = line(0) & " : " & line(1)
        End If
    End If
Next

ReDim Preserve target(j)
For i = 0 to j
    msgbox target(i)
Next
```

When you run this it should report all processes with PID < 500

Comment: Thank you very much for your efffort! I like your solution

Comment: @EdwardBlack   Thanks for the excellent question -- I wasn't aware of those options for `tasklist` until I looked at the documentation when trying to formulate the answer. I was simply trying to get a better handle on what the table looked like when I noticed those other options.